# How to insert two rows in one column with same id, different cultureId and in different Languages?

Tags: sql, culture

I have a table Culture, Companies and CompaniesLocale. In Culture table i have CultureId, CultureCode and DisplayName , in Companies i have CompanyID, Name and in CompaniesLocale I have CompanyID, CultureId, Name. I inserted to languages in culture table English and German.
Now When i create a new company how i am going to insert into  CompaniesLocale the same Name that is created in Companies but as described in different language(I Choose German but i can be maybe a Cyrillic. I want the new company to be added first to Companies then in CompaniesLocale with the same COmpanyId but the proper CultureId for the language.
Is that possible?

Comment: That all sounds reasonable and proper to me and I don't see the problem.  It seems to that this is the sequence:

1) Insert to company table, using the default/native name of the company.
2) insert to CompanyLocal table, using the name of the company for that culture. 

What is the problem?

Comment: Yes, but how i am wondering how? For example i have this data in Companies table: ID=1 Name= Microsoft AND ID=2 Name=Google, now on my CompaniesLocale table I Have ID=1 CUltureID =1 (which is for English) Name= Microsoft, alos i this table i have the same Company but in different Language for example in Cyrillic ID =1 CultureID=2(for different language or cyrillic) and NAMe should be in cyrillic for Microsoft. Am i clear?

Comment: Do you mean, What would the sql insert statement look like?

Comment: Yes, i need the sql insert script so i can run in asp.net

Comment: Can you Move your sample table and records example using Ctrl+K sot that it may look clearer for us...

Comment: Excuse me Crimsonland, but i dont understand you clearly how should i move. You want to know whats in the tables. if so Here is the table CUlture: CultureID, CultureCode, DisplayName; Companies:CompanyId, Namel CompaniesLocale:ComapnyId, CultureId, Name

Answer (score 0):

something like
insert into CompanyLocal(CompanyId, CultureId, Name) values (1, 1, 'spreken zie deutch')

Comment: OK but how about in asp.net for example when i want to create a new company, do i have to make two textboxes or do you have any idea about that?

Comment: No... in any app, you would collect the value once from the UI.  It would then be held in a variable in  your code.  You can use that same variable multiple times: for example, to execute mutliple table inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I can see two approaches.

1. Two inserts. First insert a record with the base locale name into `Company`, get the new `CompanyID`, then insert the rest of the names into `CompanyLocale` using the obtained `CompanyID`. This assumes there's a trigger `ON Company FOR INSERT` which adds the base locale name to `CompanyLocale`.
2. One insert. Insert all the names into `CompanyLocale` with empty `CompanyID` values. This also assumes using a trigger, this time it's `ON CompanyLocale FOR INSERT`. The trigger inserts a new record into `Company`, gets the new id and updates it for the newly inserted `CompanyLocale` records. Also this assumes that the foreign key column `CompanyLocale.CompanyID`, which references `Company.ID`, must allow NULL values. (With the first approach I think it can be prohibited from getting NULLs.)